# Can you query object data against a custom metadata type?

Tags: soql, custom-metadata

Is it possible to query an objects data against a custom metadata type? For instance, I'm working on a data cleanup project and need to find every lead where the value in the State field is not one of the values we can map to. I was thinking of creating a CMT of the allowable State values and writing something like:

```
select id from lead where (not state in @CMT).
```

For some context, we're talking 3million+ leads with a global database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pure SOQL, it is not possible. What you want only works as a table join, which requires a relationship between the two objects (either `Lookup` or `Master-Detail`). No such relationship is possible in either direction between a `Standard Object`/`Custom Object` and `Custom Metadata`. One is data, whereas the other is metadata.

If you're in `Apex`, then you can pull the values out of the `Custom Metadata` and into an allowlist/blocklist to use as a filter value.

Comment: and even if you decide to query for your Custom Metadata Type data, it doesn't count against the SOQL query limit for the transaction (but you should prefer the methods [oulined in the Apex Reference Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_custom_metadata_types.htm)). Using a query does count against the query rows limit though.